# how to remove item from list in JavaScript using angularjs, without loading previous items in list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a REST API which I receive data from, for instance a list of items. I have been told that the beauty of JavaScript is that you don't have to reload the whole page when some condition changes.

I hooked up angular to my API to try this out. The issue I'm having now is that after making a call to my API to delete an item the whole list (not the page, the page does not get refreshed) gets reloaded. The only thing I want to happen on my page is that the item that I have removed, gets removed from the screen without the other items in the list reloading. I tried a bunch of stuff, but nothing worked. Here is some of my code. So this is what I'm seeing on screen. I delete an item. The whole list disappears for a couple of milliseconds and then reappears, without the item I deleted of course.

reviews.html:

```
<h1>Reviews</h1>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="review in reviews track by review.id">
    <h3><a href="http://localhost:8080/videogamereviews/#!/show/{{review.id}}">{{review.title}}</a></h3>
    <p>
      {{ review.conclusie }}
    </p>
    <p><a href="http://localhost:8080/videogamereviews/#!/delete/{{review.id}}">delete this review</a>
    </p>
    <p><a href="http://localhost:8080/videogamereviews/#!/edit/{{review.id}}">edit this review</a>
    </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

app.js

```
var VideogameReviewsApp = angular.module('VideogameReviewsApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']).config(
  ['$routeProvider', '$resourceProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $resourceProvider) {
      $routeProvider.when('/', {
        controller: ReviewCtrlAll,
        templateUrl: 'reviews.html'
      }).when('/home', {
        controller: Test,
        templateUrl: 'reviews.html'
      }).

      when('/show/:id', {
        controller: ReviewCtrl,
        templateUrl: 'review.html'
      }).when('/delete/:id', {
        controller: DeleteCtrl,
        templateUrl: 'reviews.html'
      }).when('/new', {
        controller: PostCtrl,
        templateUrl: 'newreview.html'
      }).when('/edit/:id', {
        controller: EditCtrl,
        templateUrl: 'newreview.html'
      }).

      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
      $resourceProvider.defaults.stripTrailingSlashes = false;
    }
  ]);

VideogameReviewsApp.factory('Review', function($resource) {
  return $resource('http://localhost/videogamereviews/review/:id', {
      id: '@id'
    },

    {
      update: {
        method: 'PUT'
      }
    });
});

var DeleteCtrl = function($scope, Review, $routeParams, $window, $location) {
  Review.delete({
    id: $routeParams.id
  }, function() {

    $scope.reviews = Review.query();
  });
}
```

Hoping you can help out a novice coder!

Comment: I would greatly appreciate a simple example :) ,if you have the time

Comment: How are you able to get the reviews with this line of code: `$scope.reviews=Review.query();` Shouldn't `Review.query()` return a Promise?

Comment: Hmmm good question, I don't really know. But i'm not getting any errors in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to reload your page because Angular provides you with two way binding. So if you remove an item (programmatically) from your array of reviews, then your UI gets updated.

your controller should look something like this

```
function homeController ($scope, $timeout) {
      $scope.persons = [{
        name : 'A',
        age : 12
      }, {
        name : 'B',
        age : 15
      }]

      $scope.remove = function (person, index) {
        console.log(person)
        console.log(index)
        // faking api called
        $timeout(function () {
          // if your api called is succesfull
          // then remove the person from the array
          $scope.persons.splice(index, 1)
        }, 500)
      }
    }
```

and your .html file

```
<ul>
      <li ng-repeat="person in persons">
        <span>{{person.name}}</span>
        <button ng-click="remove(person, $index)">x</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

and the live demo link if you want to test it

https://jsbin.com/lizanowoqo/edit?html,output